# Vb.net code to check if a file (new version on google code) exists on the web?

Tags: vb.net, deployment

I am working on a simple FOSS VB.net program that operates mostly in one window( http://code.google.com/p/slotshuffle/ link if anyone would like to help review the code or or wants to see for reference).

I have searched online for ways to notify users of an updated version, and most of them involve changing the method of deployment or adding a lot of classes (to a program that's  only 500-odd lines including comments).

What I would like to be able to do (in pseudo code) is go to a file menu or button(ie a sub) and:

```
if http://(website...)/slotshuffle2.0.zip exists
then
msgBox.show "New version available" + a link
else
msgBox.show "No new version check back later"
```

It seems like there is a .exists method that can be used locally, but I am not quite sure if it is applicable here? Also has anyone had experience with update checks and googlecode? (i.e. is the address formed in a predictable manner such that what I am asking is feasible?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i were you the way i would do it is have a currentversion.html page on the site containing the current version number, then if you use a webrequest, described here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx  you can find that version, compare to the version of the client, then do what you need from there.

Comment: Didn't follow your suggestion exactly, but you got me thinking with the currentversion.html >>> Ended up just adding a webbrowser component and linking to the google code wiki!

Thanks to everyone that replied, Love this site!

Answer (score 3):

The first thing to point out is MsgBox will *not* show a hyperlink under any circumstances.  You have to have your own form for that.

For the actual question of how to check for a file on the web, you want to use the `System.Net.WebClient` class.  That will allow you to easily download a file from the web.

Or, use the `System.Net.HttpWebRequest` class to create a request for a file.  This is a little more complicated to use, but will allow you to request the file and get a response from the server without actually downloading the entire thing.

Comment: This is an interesting idea as well, I'm going to have to investigate more, maybe for a future release. Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 3):

If you know for sure that the file exists, you can check the [IfModifiedSince](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.ifmodifiedsince.aspx) property.

For this, you will have to store the last modified date after you have downloaded the first version & on subsequent checks, compare the file modified date with the stored date.

See the MSDN link above for an example.

Answer (score 2):

I have done something similar, although it just reads a URL for text and strips out the information I need with regex:

```
System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(oURL).Split(Chr(10))
```

I then loop through the resulting array (of lines) and process the information.

Maybe this can get you started